# Is the cartesian product of a finite amount of countable sets, countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would assume so. I know that the product of two countable sets is countable, but what about a finite number?

Comment: Yes, it is. Proved the same way as for two.

Comment: Hint: A product of $n$ sets is the product of $n-1$ sets times a set.

Comment: You can prove it by induction. If you view the cartesian product of n countable sets as itself, a countable set, then the cartesian product of n+1 countable sets is just the cartesian product TWO countable sets: the first set is a cartesian product of n sets, and the second is the n+1th set.

Comment: Two is a finite number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claim:  The cartesion product of $n$ countable set is countable for any finite/natural n.

Proof by induction:

Base cases: $n = 1$.  Then $C_1$ is countable.  Nothing more needs saying.

$n = 2$.  $C_1 \times C_2$ is countable. Why?  well, you know why, its the old diagonal list argument.  $(a_1,b_1), (a_2,b_1), (a_1,b_2),(a_3, b_1) ....etc.$

I'll assume you know it.

Inductive step:

Assume $\prod_{1}^n C_i$ is countable.

Then $\prod_1^{n+1} C_i = [\prod_1^n C_i] \times C_{n+1}$.

Now $[\prod_1^n C_i]$ is *ONE* countable set.  $C_{n+1}$ is another.  So  $[\prod_1^n C_i]\times C_{n+1}$ is the cartesian product of *TWO* countable sets.  And is thus countable.

I know, it feels like the rug being pulled from under you.  But is works.  If cartesian product of two countable sets are countable, just cluster the cartesian products of multiple sets into cluster of two.